# How do i pass csrf token with this file upload

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins, laravel-5.3

I have this html:

```
<input id="input-id" type="file" accept=".mp3, .mp4" name="file" class="form-control"><br>
<input type="hidden" id="getfilename" name="uploadedfile" value="">
```

And this jquery plugin to upload file:

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
        maxFileSize: 264000,
        uploadUrl: "{{url('/rate/uploadfile')}}", 
        uploadAsync: true,
        allowedFileExtensions: ['mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'flv'],
        maxFileCount: 1,
        showUpload: true,
        dropZoneEnabled: false
});
```

And the route under web middleware group:

```
Route::post('rate/uploadfile', 'RateController@uploadfile');
```

And whenever i try to upload the file i got the familiar error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: did you remember to add the token `{{ csrf_token() }}` to your form in the view?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII yes. but i am trying to upload the file with this plugin  before submitting the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add this code on your form 
`<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` this adds a csrf token field on your form using laravel's csrf_token() function.
Then on your script add this

```
    $("#input-id").fileinput({
            maxFileSize: 264000,
            uploadUrl: "{{url('/rate/uploadfile')}}", 
            uploadAsync: true,
            uploadExtraData:{'_token':$('#csrf_token').val()
            allowedFileExtensions: ['mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'flv'],
            maxFileCount: 1,
            showUpload: true,
            dropZoneEnabled: false
    });
```

If you are using http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input this plugin for the file upload then `uploadExtraData:{'_token':$("#csrf_token").val()},` this line should add the csrf token as an extra post parameter for the ajax request. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This Follow
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

First step add meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

second step

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
    maxFileSize: 264000,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    uploadUrl: "{{url('/rate/uploadfile')}}", 
    uploadAsync: true,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'flv'],
    maxFileCount: 1,
    showUpload: true,
    dropZoneEnabled: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the examples in this post without a good result, the configuration that works for me was

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
            uploadUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/processfile",
            enableResumableUpload: true,
            allowedFileExtensions : ['json'],
            ajaxSettings : {
                'headers': {"X-CSRFToken": crf_token},
            },
            maxFileCount: 10,
            showCancel: true,
```

reading the documentation the correct place for headers is ajaxSettings: https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#ajaxSettings

This code works well for python Django or flask, I do not know why for PHP works

```
ajaxSettings : {
                'headers': {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": crf_token},
            },
```

so for for avoiding issues I currently use

```
ajaxSettings : {
                'headers': {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': crf_token , "X-CSRFToken": crf_token},
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the csrf_token to every view and save using hidden input fields within forms. To do this place it in the header using a meta tag.

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Then you can easily access the value when using any script functions or any ajax calls by using:

```
var meta_token = $("meta[name=_token]");
```

Then like muttalebm said, Using uploadExtraData you could do the following:

```
uploadExtraData: meta_token.attr("content")
```

For testing **development** you can also add the url as an exception in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware class, This is not advised in production mode as opens you up to unwanted security risks. However if you are testing locally and not in production mode you can simply do:

`protected $except = ['/rate/uploadfile'];`  in your VerifyCsrfToken class.